# AuthorizationHandler & Cookie Authentication not playing nicely together

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-authorization, asp.net-core-authenticationhandler

I'm using simple [cookie authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-3.1) (`.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie`) and require an authenticated user by default so use:

```
options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
```

This works fine: as expected navigating to a URL when not authenticated redirects to my login page.

I've now added the custom `AuthorizationHandler` below that works with the users role.

This also works, however it seems to override the default cookie authentication behaviour, i.e. If I am not logged in & navigate to a controller decorated with my handler `[Authorize(Policy = "DemoPolicy")]` then rather than being redirected to the login page my `HandleRequirementAsync()` is invoked (and currently fails as `context.User` is `null`).

Is there a way for these things to play together? Can I change my `AuthorizationHandler` so that it recognises that there is no authenticated user & redirects to my login page?

---

**AuthorizationHandler:**

```
public class RoleHandler : AuthorizationHandler<RolesRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, RolesRequirement requirement) {
        string userRoleName = context.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(claim => claim.Type == ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType).Value;
    
        if (userRoleName == "let-me-in")
            context.Succeed(requirement);
    }
```

That uses a simple requirement

```
public class RolesRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public RolesRequirement(string role) {
        Role = role;
    }

    public string Role { get; }
}
```

I create a policy:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options => {
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();

    options.AddPolicy(SecuriyPolicies.RequireManagerRole, policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new RolesRequirement("let-me-in")));
});
```

And apply it to a controller:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "DemoPolicy")]
public class MyController : Controller {
    ...
```